# Sum all the repeat event based on dates, aggregate by 7 days ,30 days >30 days

Tags: sql, aggregate

I am trying to calculate repeat if there is a repeat event in 3,7,30 and >30 days.

In the image below the the yellow is the sql table,
the green is transformation needed, where I find out what is the first event for Event A and Event B. and then find out what is the gap between the first event of A and next events of A.

Finally I need to aggregate and achieve the blue table where data is aggregate for the unique events.

I have been trying to achieve this in SQL but I am stuck as I am not sure how to filter and loop.

[Original data and Expected outcome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdGV1.png)

Comment: Providing your data as TEXT (not as PICTURE), will help other answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE @reference_date DATE = '2022-08-02';
SELECT
  Event,
  MIN(Date)  as First_date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @reference_date, Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Within_3_Days",
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @reference_date, Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 6
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Within_7_Days",
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @reference_date, Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 29
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Within_30_Days",
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @reference_date, Date)>=30
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ">_30_Days"
FROM event e0
GROUP BY Event
```

output:

| Event | First_date | Within_3_Days | Within_7_Days | Within_30_Days | >_30_Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-08-01 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 2022-09-15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

- The `@reference_date` is used to reference the date needed to determine if a date is within x days.

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/cnITPPmv)

P.S.  I use dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD, because that's the only way I am SURE about the ordering of the Day and the Month part.

EDIT:
When using the first date of an event to determine the 'within' columns, you can do:

```sql
SELECT
  e0.Event,
  MIN(e0.Date)  as First_date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, e1.Date, e0.Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Within_3_Days",
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, e1.Date, e0.Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 6
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Within_7_Days",
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, e1.Date, e0.Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 29
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Within_30_Days",
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, e1.Date, e0.Date)>=30
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ">_30_Days"
FROM event e0
INNER JOIN (SELECT Event,MIN(Date) as Date from event GROUP BY Event) e1 on e1.Event=e0.Event
GROUP BY e0.Event
```

see: [DBFIDDLE2](https://dbfiddle.uk/6hc-PIgf)

Comment: Thank you @Luuk, One additional question is how can the  reference_date be dynamic which takes the first event date. For Example, for Event A, the reference_date is 2022-08-01 and for Event B , the reference_date should be 2022-09-15. ( It is the first occurance date of that event ) So technically the Event B will have 0 repeat events within 3, 7,30 and >30 days

Comment: I replaced the variable by the output of a sub-table (`SELECT Event,MIN(Date) ....`), see EDIT